# ReapetedType field not expendable in dump debug mode

Tags: symfony4

as you can see in the picture below, when i dump the $errors object i can expend only two children but not the third, a RepeatType field, I can access it only by dumping the $error in loop.

As anyone had this kind of weird behaviour ? is there some options to set to be able to access all children of the dumped object ?

[image: bug with dump]

Answer (score 0):

After a few searches, i find out that there is an option that you can add allow/disable the field to be passed to the parent field or form.

It is the `error_bubbling` option, set at `false` by default in the Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType.

In the code like this :

```
$builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('username', TextType::class)
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
                'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
                'error_bubbling' => true,
            ))
        ;
```

But i don't know why it is like that by default is this a security pratice ?